# Website can't load when I run two Wordpress site in a single instance of AWS

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, error-handling, virtualhost

My two websites is hosted at AWS. Both two websites managed using virtual host and I've also an elastic IP address that points from my namecheap domains.

When one Wordpress site is run then no problem occurred. Even when I run another site with basic PHP file then both site run perfectly. But when install Wordpress in second website then both website seems not able to load. Says "Taking too much time to load". I can't even give any command over putty/ssh at that time. It's behave like hangs for forever. Unless stop and run the instance from aws console I can't do anything.

Interesting things is that sometime both website load for few minutes and again both website down.

Comment: What instance is that? Maybe you need more powerful one?

Comment: Currently it is in Free tier, t2.micro and there is no traffic on both website. Just starting to build the website. I thought it would be some configuration or anything about .htaccess file.